# MOSFET blow up in UPS

Tags: mosfet, ups

I have seen many UPS circuits in which MOSFET transistors have been blown up in their inverter part. According to following circuit what are the  various failures that can cause this to happen?

[image]

Comment: Personally, I don't like shorting the gates of parallelled MOSFETs which can cause unwanted oscillations. It's always a good practice to use a suitable series resistor for each MOSFET's gate. Besides, I don't see any protection (e.g. snubber) for MOSFETs. Since the MOSFETs switch an inductive load (i.e. the respective half of the primary winding), the back emf may cause the drain voltage to excess the abs max rating of the MOSFET. For example, even if the battery voltage is 12VDC, the drains may see 60VDC. This spike's duration may be quite short but it can be killer for the MOSFETs.

Comment: Listen to @Rohat! You must have individual gate resistors.

Comment: I would also use a proper gate driver, not a random diode with pull-down resistor (which will be very slow to turn off).

Comment: This is also a **poorly** designed circuit. For example: switching the MOSFETs off relies on a single 10 k resistor while the SG3525 has push/pull outputs. Also see Rohat's comments. So TLDR: it's a **crap** design so you can expect your devices to be damaged.